# Unexpected pipe 'ValuesPipe' imported by the module 'HomieModule'

Tags: angular, import, module, pipe

Im having problems while importing a Pipe with this setup:  I have a dashboard.Module which connects with Homie.Module and Services.Module via Dashboard-routing.Module

This is my **Dashboard.Module**

```
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';    
import { ValuesPipe } from './values-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ DashboardRoutingModule, CommonModule],
  providers:    [ HomieService, ServiceService ],
  declarations: [ DashboardComponent, ValuesPipe],
  exports: [ValuesPipe],
  bootstrap:    [ DashboardComponent ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**Homie.Module**

```
import { ValuesPipe } from './../values-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomieRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    ValuesPipe
  ],
  declarations: [HomieListComponent, HomieDetailComponent]
})
export class HomieModule { }
```

**Service.Module**

```
import { ValuesPipe } from './../values-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ServiceRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    ValuesPipe
  ],
  declarations: [ServiceDetailComponent, ServiceListComponent]
})
export class ServiceModule { }
```

**Error**

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected pipe 'ValuesPipe' imported by the module 'HomieModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected pipe 'ValuesPipe' imported by the module 'HomieModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

When I declare my pipe in Homie and Service modules I get the error message: pipe declared in two modules.
So thats why I moved my pipe to Dashboard.module which is the module that connects with both (Parent).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By design convention implemented design is wrong.
If you want to share pipes, components, directives which are common to your project modules, you should use SharedModule concept.

In your solution, you are doing exporting pipe correctly but just that way it doesn't work.

Once you export `common pipe(s), component(s) and directive(s)` after doing so you have to **`import that entire module from where you have exported such things to other modules where you want to use them`**. So do following,

**1)** Create a shared module somewhere in your project directory

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';

import { ValuesPipe}         from './../values-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ ValuesPipe ],
  exports:      [ ValuesPipe ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**2)** Import shareModule in `Service.Module`

```
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
...
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ServiceDetailComponent, ServiceListComponent]
})
export class ServiceModule { }
```

Now you are ready to use exported pipe in `Service Module`.

Read more about **[shareModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules)**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't create another module because I used DashboardModule as the shared one. The answer was perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: You can't have DashboardModule as you shared module as it contains bootstrap process. So don't make a shared module rather create a new one.

Comment: Ok, I think i had another mistake then: I have another module (app.module) which the bootstrap declaration.

Comment: Then its fine. But I observed you have bootstrap meta property in Dashboard too. So just pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification tho, I deleted the bootstrap declaration from dashboard.module

Comment: I can't get this to work do they still need to be imported in angular 5?

Comment: Thanks so much for this; it works with a shared library, too

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the pipe so a service module to make it work with Angular7. This worked for me:

https://alligator.io/angular/providers-shared-modules/